# how to create multiple countdown timers in c# windows application form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I had created multiple timers using for loop and the timers are diplayed in the corresponding labels.If i click the button "n" times then "n" times ll be created.This code shows error in time countdown during runtime. Each timer is getting decremented by different intervals.How to resolve this problem?

```
    public Dictionary<Timer, Label> dict = new Dictionary<Timer, Label>();

    int n = 1;
    int timesec = 10;
    private void CreateTimers()
    {                        
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();


            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Interval = (1000);//1 sec

            Label label = new Label();
            label.Name = "label" + i;
            label.Location = new Point(0, 100 + i * 30);
            label.TabIndex = i;
            label.Visible = true;

            this.Controls.Add(label);

            dict[timer] = label;

            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();

        }

     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //function call
        CreateTimers();
         n++;
     }
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       //timer countdown
        Timer t = (Timer)sender;
        timesec--;
        if (timesec == 0)
            t.Stop();
        dict[t].Text = timesec.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us error message? Also you are sharing `timesec` between timers. Could you also explain exactly what you want to achieve as using multiple timers is probably not the best idea.

Comment: Use only *one* Timer, its only job is to update the labels.  Its Interval property is not critical, 45 msec is plenty fast enough.  For each label, store the DateTime.UtcNow value when you start timing it.  And subtract that from DateTime.UtcNow when you update it to know how much time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues.  First and foremost, you have to eliminate that loop, since that creates more timers than you probably realize.  Also, since you want each timer to be independent, you can't change the timesec value.

Try using the value of the label to show the count down, something like this:

```
private void CreateTimer() {
  System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
  timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
  timer.Interval = (1000);//1 sec

  Label label = new Label();
  label.Name = "label" + n.ToString();
  label.Text = timesec.ToString();
  label.Location = new Point(0, 100 + n * 30);
  label.Visible = true;
  this.Controls.Add(label);

  dict.Add(timer, label);
  timer.Enabled = true;
  timer.Start();
  n++;
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = (System.Windows.Forms.Timer)sender;
  Label l = dict[t];
  int labelTime = 0;
  if (Int32.TryParse(l.Text, out labelTime)) {
    labelTime -= 1;
  }
  l.Text = labelTime.ToString();
  if (labelTime == 0) {
    t.Stop();
  }
}
```